# How to Have and Modify and "Local Variable" in a Sum

Tags: summation

Let's say I have polynomial $P(n,i)=(i+1)(n+1)^2$. I want to sum $k$ $P$'s, but with a twist: $n$ for any $P$ is based upon the $P$'s before it. So, in code, what I want is this:

```
def P(n,i):
  return i*(n**2)

V=0
S=0
for i in range(k):
  S+=P(V,i)
  V+=P(V,i)

print(S)
```

However, of course, I want to formulate this in a more mathematical notation. So, how can I keep a "local variable" $V$ in a sum and modify it across each term?

Comment: I think no, just use a recursive fashion: $S_0=0,\,V_0=0,\,S_i=S_{i-1}+P(V_{i-1},i),\,V_i=V_{i-1}+P(V_{i-1},i)$

Comment: At the moment, both $V$ and $S$ remain $0$ forever....

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah, I just realized that, but it's just an example function, the actual values don't actually matter.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin So there's no other way?